# Notepad++ multiline file toolbar

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to make the toolbar in notepad++ that holds the files extend to more than 1 line instead of having an arrow that lets you scroll to the right when you have many files open in it

Comment: Are you building Notepad++ from source?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the Preferences Dialog

```
Settings -> Preferences
```

On the General Tab, there is a **Tab Bar** section. Check the **Multi-line** check box.

Answer (score 0):

Options -> Interface 1 -> on the right side you can finde "Tabs" and there should be a checkbox called "Multiline"

I hope you can find this. I translated it from the german version of Notepad++